# How to properly store login info in database

Tags: database, database-design, database-security

I wanna to design an authentication database which has the following functions:

1. I used Bcrypt so I need to store the salted password in the dB
2. I only allow user login to one device at a time, so I need to check if the user is currently logged in. (is_logged_in)
3. I need users to verify their email/phone before adding them into the account (email_verified, phone_verified)
4. I want to store all the user's info (firstName, lastName, dateOfBirth, etc.)
5. I want users to create at most three security questions/answers before using
6. I want to store users' passed logged in info (Time, location, etc.)
7. I want to share this database between my multiple apps, i.e. use one account to log in my multiple apps

So I Designed the following tables (Primary Key is in bold):

*Authentication_Info*
**UID** | Password_salt | Is_logged_in | Email_Verified | Phone_Verified

*User_Info*
**UID** | FirstName | LastName  | Email | Location  | RegisterDate  | PhoneNumber   | DateOfBirth | isEnabled

*SecurityQ/A*
**UID** | **SID** | SecurityQuestion    | SecurityAnswer

*Passed_login_info*
**UID** | **Time**  | Location  | IP    | Device

After I changed them to 3NF, I got the following tables (Again, primary Key is in bold):

*Authentication_Info*
**UID** | Password_salt | Is_logged_in

*User_Info*
**UID** | FirstName | LastName  | Email_id  | Location  | RegisterDate  | Phone_id  | DateOfBirth

*SecurityQ/A*
**UID** | **SID** | SecurityQuestion    | SecurityAnswer

*Passed_login_info*
**UID** | **PID** | Time    | Location  | IP    | Device

*Token_Verification*
**Verification_id** | **UID** | TempToken   | Expire_Time

Is this a good design? Any mistakes I made?

Comment: Perhaps I've not head enough caffeine, but your primary key and foreign keys are not clear to me, what I assume you mean by UID/ SID/PID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I'm not familiar with the intended use of the application, I can't say for sure if the advice below is applicable in this situation, but regardless, here are some suggestions:

1. Regarding the `Token_Verification` table, I believe only three fields are required: `UID`, `TempToken`, `Expire_Time`. I don't see the need for `Verification_id`.
2. The `Authentication_Info` table does not need a field for `Is_logged_in` because we can check if a `UID` is logged-in by searching the `Token_Verification` table for a valid `TempToken`. Thus, this field can be removed.
3. The `Password_salt` field in the `Authentication_Info` table should be separated into `Salt` and `SaltedHash_Password`. When a password arrives for validation, you will have to prepend the salt, hash the `(salt + password)` and compare against the stored value.
4. In the `SecurityQ/A` table, you should treat `SecurityAnswer` as if it were a password. Each security answer should be stored with a unique random salt. Thus, the fields of the table should be `UID`, `SID`, `SecurityQuestion`, `Salt`, `SaltedHash_SecurityAnswer`.

The tables I haven't mentioned above look fine to me :)

```
       (\(\
       ).. \
       \Y_, '-.
         )     '.
         |  \/   \ 
         \\ |\_  |_
         ((_/(__/_,'.
              (,----'
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the recommendation, yes, I need to encrypt the security answer! Thx! :)